# useState is not re-rendering with push, unshift and pop on an array state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to update the usersData variable created using useState so that anytime someone clicks on add user, a data object is added to the beginning of usersData, but the problem is that it only works with spread operators and not with push, pop, or unshift operations, as seen in the code below.

The code below is functioning great, and it updates and re-renders every time `usersData` changes:

```js
const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState([]);

  const receiveUserData = (data) => {
    const dataUpdated = [data, ...usersData];
    setUsersData(dataUpdated);
  };
```

However, `dataUpdated` has the same data as above code, the following code does not re-renders the page:

```js
const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState([]);

  const receiveUserData = (data) => {
    let dataUpdated = usersData;
    dataUpdated.unshift(data);
    setUsersData(dataUpdated);
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second attempt, using `unshift` does not cause a re-render because, for React, nothing has changed, since you are giving the same `reference` to `setUsersData`. In fact `unshift` updates the content without affecting the reference; so `dataUpdated` === `usersData`.

Every time you need to update an `Object` or an `Array` to have a re-render, you need to create a new `reference`. And the spread operator does that, and this is why your first attempt is working, which is:

```js
const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState([]);

const receiveUserData = (data) => {
  const dataUpdated = [data, ...usersData];
  setUsersData(dataUpdated);
};
```